# In Google Voice, do all SMS messages have to be transmitted via a data connection?

Tags: wi-fi, sms, data-connection, google-voice, cellular-radio

If someone is using Google Voice, do they need a data connection (cellular or WiFi) to be on in order to send/receive any SMS messages?

This seems to be a big limitation, as keeping data on all the time can really drain the device's battery (and can get expensive with all of Android's background data).

Also, signal strength for a functional data connection generally has to be stronger than the minimal signal required to send/receive traditional SMS messages.  Inside buildings, it is commonly hard to get a data signal, but SMS messages can often still be transmitted/received.

Comment: If you are using the Google Voice or Hangouts app, then yes it must have a working data connection, but it's data usage will be extremely minimal. (Do people actually turn off mobile data anymore?!?!) But in Google Voice you can setup your SMS messages to forward to email or an actual SMS number if you prefer.

Comment: @acejavelin Thanks. Regarding your last sentence, do those incoming SMS get duplicated within Google Voice (or Hangouts), or is it a true forward where they *only* appear within your cellular SMS?

Comment: I haven't used anything but he app in years... I honestly don't remember but since I have no SMS messages on voice.google.com in 3 years but have them in my Hangouts, I assume it is a true relay/forward and not a copy.

Comment: Since my comments seem to have answered your question, I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Google Voice or Hangouts app to send or receive messages using your Google Voice number, then yes it must have a working data connection, but it's data usage will be extremely minimal.

In Google Voice you can setup your SMS messages to forward to email or your actual carrier's SMS service if you prefer. You can replay from either email or carrier SMS via both methods as well.

Answer (score -1):

**No**, if you're using Google Hangouts to send message then only it will use data(or when you're calling someone via Voip).

If you SMS to someone on your contact list(only phone no.) using hangouts app it'll use your service provider to send message.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm confused by your answer.  The first sentence seems to say that the Google Hangouts app uses data to send SMS, but the second sentence seems to say that the Google Hangouts app will use the service provider to send SMS.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I down voted this answer because it is very unclear... there is a distinct difference between your carrier's cellular SMS service, and Google Voice's SMS service. The carrier's SMS service even if managed by Hangouts will not use data, but sending/receiving SMS via the Google Voice number using Hangouts or Google Voice app does require and use a data connection.